# AJAX rating control: Already rated message

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, rating

I am using the AJAX rating control to rate the articles. It is working fine. But I wish to add a functionality to it. I want to give the user a message when the user has already rated the article. How can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the given ratings in DB with UserID, you can check it with a callback event in code behind. If user rated, you can place a dynamic javascript function (alert, etc.) with `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`